# java download manager in debugger

Tags: java

Sometimes during debugging the sun.jkernel.DownloadManager appears. Why does that happen?

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/jkernel/DownloadManager.java.html

```
/**
 * Handles the downloading of additional JRE components.  The bootstrap class
 * loader automatically invokes DownloadManager when it comes across a resource
 * that can't be located.
 *
 *@author Ethan Nicholas
 */
 public class DownloadManager extends BootClassLoaderHook {
```

Comment: What are you debugging and what version of the JDK are you running?

Comment: jdk 6. Debugging junit tests.